# Cannot autowire (...) it references class "WSDL\WSDLCreator" but no such service exists

Tags: symfony, autowired

I installed package `composer require georgo/wsdl-creator`.

The path to file I wanted to use is: `vendor/georgo/wsdl-creator/src/WSDL/WSDLCreator.php`

Inside this file it has namespace and class:

```
namespace WSDL;

class WSDLCreator
{
...
```

`vendor/georgo/wsdl-creator/composer.josn` has following code:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "WSDL\\": "src/",
```

In my controller I used that class: `use WSDL\WSDLCreator;`

Then I wanted to use it `public function createWSDL(WSDLCreator $WSDLCreator){...}`

Then exception happened:

> Cannot autowire argument $WSDLCreator of
> "App\Controller\SOAPController::createWSDL()": it references class
> "WSDL\WSDLCreator" but no such service exists.

I tried to modify that composer.json with additional "WSDL" since there is "WSDL" folder after "src":

`"WSDL\\": "src/WSDL"`

After clearing the cache multiple times the same exception happened.

Please help.

Comment: This is unrelated to auto-loading. Leave the `composer-json` file alone. You are trying to autowire a service that does not exist. Read more about Symfony's [DI autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added record to services.yaml

```
WSDL\WSDLCreator:
        autowire: true
```

and it works now but generated obvious problems because third party packages aren't services and they has no type hints in constructors and in this case WSDLCreator is not even a bundle.

To use this package I had to just create a new object `new WSDLCreator()` in my method.

Comment: You might want to see if there is a WSDL-Bundle package.  A bundle is a Symfony wrapper for a third party library which, among other things, defines various services.

Comment: Sorry but there is no way I could find any bundle to create .wsdl files. It's because this functionality is rare. I wish Symfony was much more popular and had millions of up to date bundles. Well since version 4 we are on the right way ;)

Comment: You are perhaps misunderstanding my suggestion.  A bundle is a wrapper.  You would still have the original wsdl package installed.  The wrapper would merely make some wsdl services available and perhaps add some configuration.  It's the sort of thing that you could consider doing if indeed you find the wsdl package useful.

Comment: I know what bundles are. Sadly it's not worth creating bundle for small and random package maintained by some random people because it costs time and such package might go out of date quickly since PHP is going fast since 7.0.